# How to mock Django View methods?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, mockito

I'm looking for a way I can mock methods in my view including create, update, partial_update.
Also, during the process of create, I make external calls where I'm uploading data to cloud, which I want to bypass during tests.
So, in addition to mocking create method, I need to mock 2 internal methods:

- _can_upload_file
- _upload_file_to_r2

I guess I need to use patch, but not sure how exactly I should use it in this context. How to achieve this?

view

```
class DatasetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data.dict()
        userid = request.user.id
        serializer = DatasetSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = self._process_dataset(data, request)  
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({"error": str(serializer.errors)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)


    def _process_dataset(self, data, request):
        r2_endpoint_public_url = getattr(settings, "R2_ENDPOINT_PUBLIC_URL", None)
        r2_dataset_folder = getattr(settings, "R2_DATASET_FOLDER", "datasets")
        size = 0
        files = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        files_info = []
        userid = request.user.id
        for file in files:
            file_info = {}
            file_info["filename"] = file.name
            filesize_check_result = self._can_upload_file(file.size, request.user.id, request.user.customer_id) # this makes external calls
            if filesize_check_result != "valid":
                return Response(
                    {"error": filesize_check_result},
                    status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                )
            self._upload_file_to_r2(data["label"], file) #this method uploads data to cloud 
            size = size + file.size

            files_info.append(file_info)

        data["dataset_details"] = files_info
        data["size"] = size

        return data
```

My current test case

```
class TestDatasetListTestCase(APITestCase):
    """
    Tests /datasets list operations.
    """

    def setUp(self):
  
        access_token = "test"


        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f"Bearer {access_token}")

        self.url = reverse("datasets-list")
        self.now = now()

        self.dataset = {
            "label": "newlabel123321",
            "desc": "dataset",
            "slug": "slug",
            "public": True,
            #"file": json.dumps(str(factory.django.FileField(filename='test.txt'))),
            "file": self._generate_file(),
            "url": "http://example.com/",
            "metadata_url": "http://example.com/meta.json",
            "size": 1024,
            "owner": "google-oauth2|115349827304074574423",
        }

    def _generate_file(self):
        f = open("test.txt", "w")
        f.write("Now the file has more content!")
        f.close()
        f = open("test.txt", "r")
        f.seek(0)
        return f

    def test_post_request_with_no_data_fails(self):
        self._generate_file()
        response = self.client.post(self.url, {})
        eq_(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def test_post_request_with_valid_data_succeeds(self):
        response = self.client.post(self.url, self.dataset, format="multipart")
        eq_(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        dataset = Dataset.objects.get(pk=response.data.get("id"))
        eq_(dataset.label, self.dataset.get("label"))
        self.dataset["id"] = response.data.get("id")
```